# Boost asio io_service dispatch vs post

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Can anyone tell me the difference between io_service [dispatch](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/dispatch.html) and [post](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/post.html)? It was not clear to me what is more suitable for my problem.

I need to invoke a handler inside another handler and I don't know what *invoker* to use.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Well, it depends on the context of the call, i.e. is it run from within the io_service or without:

- `post` will not call the function directly, ever, but postpone the call.
- `dispatch` will call it rightaway if the dispatch-caller was called from io_service itself, but queue it otherwise.

So, it depends on the function calling post/dispatch was called, and if the given handler can be called straight away or not.

*What this means:*

... is that `dispatch` might eventually call your code again (naturally, this depends on your app and how you chain calls), but in general you should **make sure your callback is re-entrant if you use `dispatch`**.

`dispatch` is thus faster, as it avoids queueing the call if possible. It comes with some caveats, so you might want needs to use `post` occasionally, or always (if you want to play it safe and can afford it).

**Update**

To incorporate some from @gimpf 's deleted answer, an older boost version had this implementation of dispatch (my comments):

```
template <typename Handler>
void dispatch(Handler handler)
{
  if (call_stack<win_iocp_io_service>::contains(this)) // called from within io_service?
    boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke(handler, &handler); // invoke rightaway
  else
    post(handler); // queue
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ~"**will not call the function directly, ever**?  How will the function get called then.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: By *directly* I mean as a descendant of the ´post()´ call you make. Instead, it will be called indirectly due to you calling poll() or a similar top-loop method that checks to see if there is any work to be done (calls to be dispatched, timers that have expired or new data on sockets, etc).

Answer (score 15):

see this blog entry:
[To post or to dispatch? - This Thread](http://thisthread.blogspot.jp/2011/06/to-post-or-to-dispatch.html)

> Running the application we'll see the difference between posting and
>   dispatching. Since it could do it, dispatch() would execute fB()
>   directly, so we'll see it runs in the current thread, and
>   synchronously. On the other side, post() would ask to io_service to do
>   the job, asynchronously in another thread, and it immediately returns
>   the control to the caller.