# What is the difference between post and dispatch from boost::asio when overloads with executor parameter are used?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I saw several questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326588/boost-asio-io-service-dispatch-vs-post), regarding post vs dispatch when only handler is passed which is posted on associated executor. I understand that dispatch can invoke synchronous call of handler without queueing it, when current execution is performed on the associated executor. I thought the same principle would be applied to [second overload](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/dispatch/overload2.html), but it is specifically said in the documentation that `The function object is queued for execution, and is never called from the current thread prior to returning from dispatch()`.

So what is the difference between post and dispatch in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're linking to old documentation.

Further, even in that version, the documentation for the non-executor overload [said the **exact same thing**](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/dispatch/overload1.html#:%7E:text=and%20is%20never%20called%20from%20the%20current%20thread%20prior%20to%20returning%20from%20dispatch), so the purported difference didn't exist.

I think it was an oversight¹ in documentation, even then, and [current versions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/dispatch.html) make it clear that the handler may be invoked prior to return:

> The function object may be called from the current thread prior to returning from dispatch()

### Side Note

I'd like to note that invocation can *still* be optimized even if *not* invoked before returning from `dispatch` itself, because

- the handler maybe pushed to a local queue instead and be executed immediately after returning from a currently executing handler. This may actually be **better** for allocation/deallocation ordering patterns.
- the handler may have an associated executor for immediate execution. This is a new feature

---

¹ the fixup was in the [commit 0340c15e4 `Fix up dispatch() documentation. Clarify distinction between post() and defer().`](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/commit/0340c15e499382da12d82c039a2ad65fa9fcd3f5) (Mar 7 2019(

Comment: Added the link to the documentation [fix](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/commit/0340c15e499382da12d82c039a2ad65fa9fcd3f5)

Comment: Just for completeness, [`co_spawn()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/co_spawn.html) is essentially the same as `post()` but for `-fcoroutines`  right?

Comment: @JimB I think it's just doing more. `co_spawn` creates the coroutine thread (frame) first and then posts its initial resumption to the executor.